# MySQL: Search & Replace with target having linefeeds/carriage returns?

Tags: mysql, replace, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm needing to cleanup our database and need to mass replace something like this:

```
<div class="rtecenter"><br />
<font color="#990033"><strong>I'm so hot, I sometimes spontaneously combust.</strong></font><br />
<img src="http://i476.photobucket.com/albums/rr124/redacted/coollogo_com_63811610.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

(I'm simply going to remove all instances of it).

I already know how to do a mass replace (I'm using PHPMyAdmin), however The problem is that it has CR/LF's in it so I'm not sure how to add the correct string to find in the query ... just for testing, I've tried doing searches using `Char(10)` or `Char(13)` where the new lines are but no results are ever returned, (I know they are there though).

Anyone know?

Comment: have you tried \r, \n and \r\n ?

Comment: I've tried just \n (no results), just \r (no results) and then \r\n and a ton of results came back but not accurate.

Comment: Are you using a SQL statement to perform the update, or are you using some special feature of PHPMyAdmin? In the former case, please post the statement you have so far; in the latter, please add the "phpmyadmin" tag to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are only CR/LF's, then you can use this query -

```
UPDATE table
SET
  column = REPLACE(column, '<div class="rtecenter"><br />\r\n<font color="#990033"><strong>I''m so hot, I sometimes spontaneously combust.</strong></font><br />\r\n<img src="http://i476.photobucket.com/albums/rr124/redacted/coollogo_com_63811610.gif" alt="" /></div>', '');
```

If there are different line separators, then you can do it in two steps:

```
UPDATE table
SET
  column = REPLACE(column, '\r', ''); -- replace all \r\n to \n

UPDATE table
SET
  column = REPLACE(column, '<div class="rtecenter"><br />\n<font color="#990033"><strong>I''m so hot, I sometimes spontaneously combust.</strong></font><br />\n<img src="http://i476.photobucket.com/albums/rr124/redacted/coollogo_com_63811610.gif" alt="" /></div>', '');
```